# when adding views they go one below another even if width is wrap content

Tags: android, button, layout, view

I have a Linear layout then programatically I'm adding some spinners and buttons and so on, but I have xml button Wrap content (width) and then on java I add spinner (or anything else) and it goes below this view even if both views are wrap content:

```
progBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        pBarToca = new ProgressBar(this);
        pBarToca.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        linToca = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tetoca);
        linToca.addView(pBarToca);
```

and it's placed under the button of xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/tetoca">
            <TextView style="@style/StylePartida"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/te_toca_jugar" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#A7E9A9" android:onClick="callJugar"
                android:text="@string/jugar" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

### edit!!!!!!

I want textview on first line then on next line button + progressbar (for example)

Comment: What are you expecting? You're using a vertical LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `android:orientation=vertical` so the `View`s will be laid out starting at the top and going down.

If you want them to all be next to each other, remove that from your xml since the default `orientation` for a `LinearLayout` is horizontal. If you do this, you will obviously need to change the `android:width` to `wrap_content` for your `TextView` or else it will take up the entire screen.

After your comment, a `RelativeLayout` would work best here.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView 
        style="@style/StylePartida"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/te_toca_jugar"
        android:id="@+id/tvID" />  // give it an id
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/tetoca"
        android:layout_below="@/id=tvID">  // place it below the TV
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#A7E9A9" android:onClick="callJugar"
            android:text="@string/jugar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the changes in the comments. Now when you add your progressbar to the LL, it should be next to the Button. You may need some changes but this should give you approximately what you want.

Comment: edit!!!!!!
---------

I want textview on first line then on next line button + progressbar (for example)

Comment: oh thanks! I think it'll work but it also helped me to find a new way to reach my goal, same thing you did but without relative layout, it will keep as linear but thanks to the other Linear that u added, I can put this one fill horizontal, then it stays on second line but new views are added one next to the other

Comment: @DaniRoca glad it worked or got you on your way :) With layouts, there are usually multiple ways to achieve what you need. The best way depends on your exact needs to get the most efficient layout

Answer (score 0):

In your textView you are matching the parent

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

This will cause the textview to take up the entire width of the parent view.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" will cause the elements to be stacked.
```

If you are using `"horizontal"` it's important not to have a child element with width matching parent.

[image: horizontal orientation with wrapped content on child elements]

EDIT:

After OPs change to question:

I have used a textview, two buttons and listview to give you an idea of how you can format it. There are many ways to achieve the same thing, this is one suggestion.
The internal linearlayout has a horizontal orientation (by default).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_marginTop="6dp"  
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="te_toca_jugar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#A7E9A9" 
    android:text="jugar"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#A7E9A9"
    android:text="jugar2"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: New layout]

Comment: edit!!!!!!
---------

I want textview on first line then on next line button + progressbar (for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/tetoca">
        <TextView style="@style/StylePartida"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/te_toca_jugar"
            android:text="@string/te_toca_jugar" />
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#A7E9A9" android:onClick="callJugar"

            android:text="@string/jugar" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try it now . the textView width was match_parent

Comment: I'm not understanding what u want to do.
u need to dynamically add more view and they should be aligned horizontally on the same line ??

Comment: edit!!!!!!
---------

I want textview on first line then on next line button + progressbar (for example)